# How can I translate this part in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to translate a part of the Wordpress comments but there is no place to edit in the theme that I use. So when someone comments a text like this appears:

```
USERNAME said 2 days ago (Reply)
```

How can I edit/translate this part?

Comment: is depends on your theme

Comment: To edit see the `comments.php` in your theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all seems to me, that you have an english installation of wordpress, and run a (probably custom) theme in a different language. If this is right, this fix will probably help:

You aren't able to translate, because you probably won't have a function for displaying comments in your theme's **functions.php**. To fix that, you'll have to call `wp_list_comments()` with a custom value for the 'callback'-parameter, for example:

```
<ul class="commentlist">
  <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=mytheme_commentdisplay'); ?>
</ul>
```

To make this work, you'll also need a function called 'mytheme_commentdisplay' in your **functions.php**:

```
function mytheme_commentdisplay ($comment, $args, $depth) {
  // ...
}
```

For a complete example, see [this page from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments#Comments_Only_With_A_Custom_Comment_Display). You can copy the function, and modify it to your needs.

If you're using .po- or .mo-files for translation, change all calls like `_e(...)`, `__(...)` and `_n(...)` to look like this example `_e('Text to be translated', 'translationslug')`.

Otherwise you can change/hardcode all occurencies of english text to your locale.

#### That should work. All necessary steps are fullfilled.

*Optionally*, for future compatibility note also the following:

You'll need to have a file called `comments.php` in your theme directory. At the time of writing, if you don't have a special comments-template or a `comments.php`-file, the comments template of WordPress is included from the file `wp-includes/theme-compat/comments.php`. The WordPress-Team will remove that functionality in future releases (see this code for reference: [source code browser](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L911)).

You can take the code from [wp-includes/theme-compat/comments.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/theme-compat/comments.php), create a comments.php-file in your template directory and paste the code in your **comments.php** file.
The function call `_deprecated_file(...)` at the top can be removed.